# Node.js: order of execution of middleware and callback functions?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express

I am fairly new to node.js, I have a starting point as `app.js`, It calls a file called `xmlParser.js` which parses an input xml file using the `xml2js` node module. This is what `app.js` looks like,

```
//include the modules
var express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    ejs = require('ejs'),
    xmlParser = require('./utils/xmlParser.js');

//save the pain of writing .ejs after each render
app.set("view engine","ejs");

//these will hold the result of the function in the file xmlParser
var listJSON, logJSON = {};

app.get('/portfolio', function(req, res, next){
    //call parse function in file xmlParser.js
    xmlParser.parse(__dirname + "/xml/svn_log.xml", listJSON);
    xmlParser.parse(__dirname + "/xml/svn_list.xml", logJSON);
    console.log("middleware was excuted!");
    next();
}, function(req, res){
    console.log(listJSON);
});
```

Now this is how the file `xmlParser.js` looks like,

```
//include the modules
var fs = require('fs'),
    xml2js = require('xml2js'),
    parser = new xml2js.Parser();

//this function parse xml file with name as filename to json and stores it in variable outputJSON
function parse(filename, outputJSON){
    fs.readFile(filename, function(err, data){
        if(err){
            console.log('cannot read file.');
        } else {
            parser.parseString(data, function(err, result){
                if(err) console.log('cannot parse file.');
                else {
                    outputJSON = result;
                }
            });
        }
    });
}

module.exports = {
    parse
}
```

Now when I run the application and go to route `/portfolio` I expect this to be printed:

```
middleware was executed!
[object]
```

But this is what I'm getting on my node console,

```
middleware was executed!
undefined
```

Now, What I want is the function in `xmlParser.js` executes and stores the parsed JSON object in the `listJSON` object which I pass to it. When I pass `listJSON` as the second argument to `parse()` function, is it pass by reference? Why am I getting 'undefined`printed when my function in the file`xmlParser.js` stores an object in it?

Comment: Make your parse function as a promise then use asynchronous/await when calling it. Otherwise you will have to add a callback function

Comment: I didn't quite understand what you meant by adding parse function as a promise and then using asynchronous/await when calling it. Could you please explain that in a bit more detail? Also, is it possible to solve this using a callback function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem is that your `parse` function calls `fs.readFile` and `parser.parseString` which are asynchronous. Second problem is that you change the object in your function: JavaScript passes parameters by object sharing. Meaning: primitive variables are passed by value: changing the parameters doesn't change the source variable. Non primitive variables like objects and arrays, cannot be changed either, but their properties can.

While indeed you call `parse` before you call `next`, asynchronosly reading the file, and then asynchronously parsing it, (without blocking your route code), makes `next` come sooner than the program finishes parsing the file.

What you can do is pipe your asynchrnous actions one by one, also make the parse return the result and you will set it after. First change your `parse` function to accept a callback and call it:

```
function parse(filename, callback){
    fs.readFile(filename, function(err, data){
        if(err){
            console.log('cannot read file.');
            return callback(err);
        } else {
            parser.parseString(data, function(err, result){
                if(err) {
                   console.log('cannot parse file.');
                   return callback(err);
                }
                else {

                    return callback(null, result);
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Then, pipe your parse functions together with the `next` function:

```
app.get('/portfolio', function(req, res, next){
    xmlParser.parse(__dirname + "/xml/svn_log.xml", function(err,  list) {
      listJSON = list;
      xmlParser.parse(__dirname + "/xml/svn_list.xml", function(err, log) {
        logJSON = log;
        next();
      });
    });
    console.log("middleware was excuted!");
}, function(req, res){
    console.log(listJSON);
});
```

Comment: Conceptually, I do understand it. But I tried running your code word for word, it still prints out undefined in the logs. I don't know why this time.

Comment: Could you try to log 'finished parsing'  at the appropriate part of you parser function, and comment the result?

Comment: I added it right after `outputJSON = result` in the 'xmlParser.js` file. this is output it showed,`middleware was excuted!
finished parsing!
finished parsing!
undefined`
Also, you can check this [github repo](https://github.com/javeria2/Web-portfolio-) for the current code I have